# Access a cell in DataGrid.SelectedItems

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to read a string from each of the the first cells of SelectedItems of the DataGrid

```
foreach (var item in myDataGrid.SelectedItems)
{
    if (item[0].ToString().Contains("Buy"))
    {
        containsBuy = true;
    }

    if (item[0].ToString().Contains("Sell"))
    {
        containsSell = true;
    }
}
```

How can I cast myDataGrid.SelectedItems? It is IList and gives object. Is there any simple and similar way to do it as it is done for one selected row of a DataGrid:

```
var row = myDataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
```

Here I can easy access any cell - row[i].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `foreach` loop to:

```
foreach (DataRowView in myDataGrid.SelectedItems)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried that before in this form (var (DataRowView)item in myDataGrid.SelectedItems) but it didn't work.